# A Poincare-like inequality

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded set with continuous boundary. Prove that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a constant $C(\epsilon)>0$ s.t.
$$
\int_{\Omega}|f(x)|^pdx\leq C(\epsilon)\int_{\Omega\backslash\Omega_\epsilon}|f(x)|^pdx+C(\epsilon)\int_{\Omega}\|\nabla f(x)\|^pdx
$$
for all $f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. where $\Omega_{\epsilon}=\{x\in\Omega: d(x,\partial\Omega)>\epsilon\}$.

I managed to prove the inequality when $n=1$ and $\Omega$ is an open interval. But I do not know how to prove it when $n\geq2$. How can I do that?

Comment: Your constant is probably going to depend on both $\Omega$ and $\epsilon$. You should try truncating $f$ near the boundary of $\Omega$ and apply the Poincare inequality to the regularizations $f_\epsilon$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Yes, the constant also depends on $\Omega$. This $\Omega$ is not necessarily connected, so the Poincare inequality may not hold.